# Dificuldades Session Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, session, c3p0

Minha aplicação web utiliza Hibernate 4.3 e faz controle de Pool de Conexão utilizando o C3P0.

As dificuldades acontecem de forma recorrente e infelizmente não consigo encontrar qual o problema que ocasiona tais erros.

Segue um dos erros:

```
org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.errorIfClosed(AbstractSessionImpl.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getTransactionCoordinator(SessionImpl.java:2065)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2065)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1862)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1838)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:909)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2551)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2537)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2367)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2362)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:496)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:229)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1260)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
    at br.com.portalserver.dao.PedidoItemDAO.selectItensPedido(PedidoItemDAO.java:37)
    at br.com.forcavendasweb.controller.PedidosFVController.carregaDadosCliente(PedidosFVController.java:498)
    at br.com.forcavendasweb.controller.PedidosFVController.doGet(PedidosFVController.java:193)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Segue partes dos códigos:

HibernateUtil.xml

```
 public class HibernateUtil {

     private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
     private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;
     private static Session session;

     public static Session getSession() {
         if (session == null || !session.isOpen()) {
             session = HibernateUtil.getFactory().openSession();
         }
         return session;
     }

     public static void closeSession() {
         if (session.isOpen()) {
             session.close();
         }
     }

     public static void commitSession() {
         if (session.getTransaction().wasCommitted()) {
             session.getTransaction().commit();
         }
     }

     public static SessionFactory getFactory() {
         if (sessionFactory == null || sessionFactory.isClosed()) {
             sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory();
         }

         return sessionFactory;
     }

     public static void closeFactory() {
         sessionFactory.close();
         StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(serviceRegistry);
     }

     private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
         try {
             Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
             serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();

             SessionFactory factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
             return factory;

         } catch (HibernateException ex) {
             System.err.println("FALHA NA CRIACAO DA SESSION FACTORY = " + ex);

             throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
         }
     } }
```

Configurações de Pool de Conexão C3P0 dentro do Hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquireIncrement">2</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.initialPoolSize">3</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.minPoolSize">3</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.maxPoolSize">8</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.maxIdleTime">1200</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.maxConnectionAge">1200</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts">1</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryDelay">250</property>
```

Métodos DAO:

```
public List<PedidoItem> selectItensPedido(Pedido ped) {
        List<PedidoItem> listaItens = Singleton.getListarItens();
        String hql = "FROM PedidoItem WHERE numped = :numped ORDER BY idpit ASC";

        session = HibernateUtil.getSession();

        try {
            listaItens = session
                    .createQuery(hql)
                    .setParameter("numped", ped.getIdped())
                    .list();

        } catch (RuntimeException erro) {
            throw erro;
        }

        return listaItens;
    }


public void editar(Entidade entidade) {
        session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
        try {
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();

            session.update(entidade);

            if (!transaction.wasCommitted()) {
                transaction.commit();
            }

        } catch (RuntimeException erro) {
            if (transaction != null) {
                try {
                    transaction.rollback();

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.err.println("==> ERRO AO FAZER ROLLBACK: " + ex.toString());
                }
            }
            System.err.println("==> ERRO ORIGINAL AO EXECUTAR A QUERY: " + erro.toString());
            throw erro;

        } finally {
            HibernateUtil.closeSession();

        }
    }
```

Após isto, o erro que acontece é o seguinte:

```
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:235)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:171)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1431)
    at br.com.portalserver.dao.PedidoItemDAO.alterarItem(PedidoItemDAO.java:164)
    at br.com.forcavendasweb.controller.PedidosFVController.doPost(PedidosFVController.java:335)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet successfully received from the server was 358,660 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 23,959 milliseconds ago.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:989)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3559)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3459)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3900)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2483)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setAutoCommit(ConnectionImpl.java:4819)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.setAutoCommit(NewProxyConnection.java:912)
    at org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider.getConnection(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:380)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:228)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Operation timed out (Read failed)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.fill(ReadAheadInputStream.java:101)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(ReadAheadInputStream.java:144)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.read(ReadAheadInputStream.java:174)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:3008)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3469)
    ... 46 more

WARN:   SQL Error: 1205, SQLState: 40001
ERROR:   Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
Grave:   ==> ERRO ORIGINAL AO EXECUTAR A QUERY: org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not execute statement
Advertência:   StandardWrapperValve[br.com.forcavendasweb.controller.PedidosFVController]: Servlet.service() for servlet br.com.forcavendasweb.controller.PedidosFVController threw exception
org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect$1.convert(MySQLDialect.java:451)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:190)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.exec.BasicExecutor.doExecute(BasicExecutor.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.exec.BasicExecutor.execute(BasicExecutor.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.exec.DeleteExecutor.execute(DeleteExecutor.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.executeUpdate(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:445)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(HQLQueryPlan.java:347)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.executeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1282)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.executeUpdate(QueryImpl.java:118)
    at br.com.portalserver.dao.PedidoItemDAO.excluirItem(PedidoItemDAO.java:138)
    at br.com.forcavendasweb.controller.PedidosFVController.doGet(PedidosFVController.java:201)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:951)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2487)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2079)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2013)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5104)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1998)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:187)
    ... 39 more
```

Estou à dias quebrando a cabeça, testando e testando incansavelmente e tal erro continua a me torturar.
Não sei mais o que pode ocasionar tais problemas.

Por favor, se alguém puder me dar uma luz.

Muito obrigado

Comment: Seu erro parece estar relacionado a conexão com banco. Já testou a mesma?

Comment: Isto aí deve ser concorrência na variável estática de sessão. Se você estiver recebendo este erro no meio de várias requisições, pode ocorrer que sua sessão feche enquanto você está tentando fazer uma consulta (por exemplo, qdo ocorre um erro em outra requisição). O principal culpado disto no seu código é o uso de variáveis estáticas para a Session, pois a mesma Session não deveria ser usada por diferentes threads.

Comment: @Dherik vou fazer a alteração sugerida.  Confesso que não havia pensado nesta questão.  Reportarei qual será o resultado.  Muito obrigado

Comment: @RogérioEduardSchaefer, funcionando me avise, que preparo uma resposta melhor ou tentamos outra coisa se não funcionar.

Comment: @Douglas, a conexão está ok.  Não encontrei nenhum erro referente a conexão com o Banco.  De qualquer forma, farei mais testes e atentarei à esta questão.  Muito obrigado

Comment: @Dherik, transformei as Session em non-static e os erros citados acima não ocorreram mais.  Porém minha aplicação contém várias requisições (select, insert, update, delet) e com isto a quantidade de sessões abertas no banco de dados aumentou mais de 200 vezes.  As sessões sendo não estáticas não reutilizam as sessões abertas no BD e a cada requisição, abre novas sessões.

Comment: Certo. Provavelmente agora é um problema de não estar fechando as sessões. Você precisa fechar a sessão a cada fim de transação. Você precisa criar este controle de abrir uma nova sessão a cada thread, iniciar a transação, fazer a operação que quer fazer, commitar a transação (ou dar rollback em caso de erro) e fechar a sessão ao final de tudo.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76803/discussion-between-rogerio-eduard-schaefer-and-dherik).

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

Creio que o problema que esteja tendo aí seja de concorrência com a variável `session`. Você está compartilhando uma mesma sessão entre várias classes e métodos e, em algum momento, uma delas está fechando a sessão e impactando nos outros métodos que estão tentando utilizá-la.

Isto ocorre por causa deste código:

```
private static Session session;
```

Experimente remover este campo `session` de dentro do `HibernateUtil` e passar a utilizar uma mesma instância da `Session` apenas no método que o utiliza. Algo assim:

```
public List<PedidoItem> selectItensPedido(Pedido ped) {
        List<PedidoItem> listaItens = Singleton.getListarItens();
        String hql = "FROM PedidoItem WHERE numped = :numped ORDER BY idpit ASC";

        Session session = HibernateUtil.getFactory().openSession();
```

E ao final do método, você fecha o `session` dentro do `finally`.

E no HibernateUtil ficaria:

```
public static Session openSession() {
     return HibernateUtil.getFactory().openSession();;
}
```

Se estiver tendo problemas em gerenciar a sessão e transação, recomendo a utilização de um Framework como o [Spring](https://spring.io) para cuidar desta burocracia para você.

Comment: fiz as alterações sugeridas por você e os problemas mencionados acima não ocorreram mais.  Acredito que tenha solucionado esta questão.  Continuarei testando.  Muito obrigado pela excelente ajuda.